# Finding final bearing of a ship given its initial bearing, initial coordinate, and final longitude

Tags: geometry, spherical-coordinates, spherical-geometry

So I’m new to this spherical trig and great circle route stuff. The question says:

There is a ship departing from point A (84° W, 15°S) on a great circle route. If its initial bearing is 70°, then what is its bearing when it crosses the 34° W longitude line?

From what I understand, you need two points to find a final bearing, but this only gives one point and I don’t know how to find the latitude when the ship is on the 34° longitude.

The answer to the question is apparently 66° if that helps anyone with reverse checking their math or anything.

Comment: The departure point and the initial bearing determine a plane though the center of the earth.  The intersection of that plane is the great circle the ship follows.  You need to find where the plane crosses the destination longitude.

Comment: Do you possible have a link to a page or a formula for this. Sorry I’m only 18 studying these new concepts so all of this is new to me.

Comment: No, I don't.  I can see where the information you need comes from, but don't have the formulas to use it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think I've got it...

Start with the isosceles triangle intersecting the North Pole, the initial point (15,84) and the point (15,34). The top of that triangle (call it $A'$) is

$$A' = 84 - 34 = 50^\circ.$$

The side $c$ is easily computed using the initial latitude

$$c = 90 - (-15) = 105^\circ.$$

We can then use the identity $$\cos a = \cos b' \cos c + \sin b' \sin c \cos A'$$
where I've labeled $b'$ as the equivalent of $c$ but on the opposite side.
So now that we have $A', c$, and $a$, we can compute $C=B'$ via

$$\frac{\sin C}{\sin c} = \frac{\sin A'}{\sin a}.$$

We can then compute $B$ using the initial heading
$$B = C - 70.$$

Finally, we can compute $A$ (no prime) which is the initial heading via

$$\cos A = -\cos B \cos C + \sin B \sin C \cos a.$$

Doing all that, I end up with $a = 66.04^\circ .$

I think that's correct. Sorry for the terrible picture.

[image]

Comment: I’m definitely still lost. How did you find the value for C? Also this question is pulled from a math competition where the questions are designed to take no longer than 40 seconds so I feel there has to be some easier way.

Comment: We know angle $A$ as the difference in longitude, and we know side $c$ as the difference in latitude by design. The black triangle is isosceles, so we know $B'$ and $b'$. We can then use one of the spherical trig cosine identities to calculate $a$. Then we use the spherical sign identity to compute angle $C$. Does that make sense?

Comment: So how exactly do we know B’ and b’? Something to do with the 70 degree bearing? I typically learn best once i know what every single side and angle equals and then I can work backward to find out how that value was obtained.

Comment: Actually, I drew an image similar to what you have and messed around with it for a bit and think I found how the formula work’s consistently! Thanks for the help